# sort by weighted values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am creating a list using a JSON file that displays boroughs and their macro neighborhoods. The boroughs and macro neighborhoods should be ordered ascending by weight and thats where I am having a problem. Below are the code for the HTML and the JSON file. Thank you in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
    <title>Code Challenge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Coding Challenge</h1>
    <p>Click a neighborhood in the box on the left to highlight the borough in the box on the right</p>

    <!-- The data is stored in a file as a javascript variable: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="datafile.js"></script>

    <!--Define the basic screen layout as two divs side by side -->
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div id="area_a" class="app_list"></div>
        <div id="area_b" class="app_list"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Grab jQuery for click handling: -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = locationData['data'];

            <!--Iterate through the JSON object and convert boroughs, macros, and neighborhoods to HTML objects-->
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var item = data[i];
                var divA = document.createElement("div");
                var divB = document.createElement("div");
                var boroughName = item.borough.name;
                divB.setAttribute("class", toClassName(boroughName));
                divA.appendChild(document.createTextNode(boroughName));
                document.getElementById('area_a').appendChild(divA);
                document.getElementById('area_b').appendChild(divB);
                divB.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.borough.name));

                var ulMappings = document.createElement('ul');
                for (var j = 0; j < item.mappings.length; j++) {
                    var map = item.mappings[j].macro;

                    if(map.name == boroughName){
                        console.log("EQUAL");
                        var liMacro = document.createElement("li");
                        ulMappings.appendChild(liMacro);
                        liMacro.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                        ulMappings.className = "ul-unlisted";
                    } else{
                        var liMacro = document.createElement("li");
                        liMacro.appendChild(document.createTextNode(map.name));
                        ulMappings.appendChild(liMacro);
                    }

                    var ulHood = document.createElement('ul');
                    for (var k = 0; k < item.mappings[j].neighborhoods.length; k++) {
                        var hoodName = item.mappings[j].neighborhoods[k].name;
                        var liHood = document.createElement('li');
                        liHood.setAttribute("class", toClassName(boroughName));
                        liHood.appendChild(document.createTextNode(hoodName));
                        ulHood.appendChild(liHood);
                    }
                    liMacro.appendChild(ulHood);
                }
                document.getElementById('area_a').appendChild(ulMappings);
            }

            <!-- Handler for clicking on a neighborhood -->
              $('#area_a ul li ul li').click(function() {
                  var clickedClass = $(this).attr("class");
                  $('#area_b div').removeClass("highlight");
                  $('#area_b div.' + clickedClass).addClass("highlight");
              });
        });

        <!-- Helper function to convert borough names to valid HTML class names -->
        function toClassName(string) {
            var newString = string.replace(' ', '');
            return newString.toLowerCase();
        }

    </script>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the Json file I am using:

```
"data": [
{
  "borough": {
    "name": "Manhattan",
    "id": 18,
    "weight": 1
  },
  "mappings": [
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Below 14th St",
        "id": 19,
        "weight": 1
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 20,
          "name": "Battery Park City"
        },
        {
          "id": 21,
          "name": "Civic Center"
        },
        {
          "id": 22,
          "name": "East Village"
        },
        {
          "id": 23,
          "name": "Financial District"
        },
        {
          "id": 24,
          "name": "Greenwich Village"
        },
        {
          "id": 25,
          "name": "Little Italy"
        },
        {
          "id": 26,
          "name": "Lower East Side"
        },
        {
          "id": 27,
          "name": "NoHo"
        },
        {
          "id": 28,
          "name": "Nolita"
        },
        {
          "id": 29,
          "name": "SoHo"
        },
        {
          "id": 30,
          "name": "TriBeCa"
        },
        {
          "id": 31,
          "name": "Union Square"
        },
        {
          "id": 32,
          "name": "West Village"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "14th to 59th St",
        "id": 33,
        "weight": 2
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 34,
          "name": "Flatiron"
        },
        {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "Gramercy"
        },
        {
          "id": 36,
          "name": "Kips Bay"
        },
        {
          "id": 37,
          "name": "Koreatown"
        },
        {
          "id": 38,
          "name": "Midtown East"
        },
        {
          "id": 39,
          "name": "Murray Hill"
        },
        {
          "id": 41,
          "name": "Chelsea"
        },
        {
          "id": 42,
          "name": "Hell's Kitchen"
        },
        {
          "id": 43,
          "name": "Midtown West"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Upper East",
        "id": 44,
        "weight": 3
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 45,
          "name": "East Harlem"
        },
        {
          "id": 46,
          "name": "Roosevelt Island"
        },
        {
          "id": 47,
          "name": "Upper East Side"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Upper West",
        "id": 48,
        "weight": 4
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 49,
          "name": "Central Park"
        },
        {
          "id": 50,
          "name": "Upper West Side"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Above 125th St",
        "id": 51,
        "weight": 5
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 52,
          "name": "Harlem"
        },
        {
          "id": 53,
          "name": "Inwood"
        },
        {
          "id": 54,
          "name": "Washington Heights"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "borough": {
    "name": "Brooklyn",
    "id": 55,
    "weight": 2
  },
  "mappings": [
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Brooklyn Heights",
        "id": 307,
        "weight": 1
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 65,
          "name": "Brooklyn Heights"
        },
        {
          "id": 77,
          "name": "DUMBO"
        },
        {
          "id": 79,
          "name": "Downtown Brooklyn"
        },
        {
          "id": 117,
          "name": "Vinegar Hill"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "BoCoCa",
        "id": 306,
        "weight": 2
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 62,
          "name": "Boerum Hill"
        },
        {
          "id": 69,
          "name": "Carroll Gardens"
        },
        {
          "id": 72,
          "name": "Cobble Hill"
        },
        {
          "id": 73,
          "name": "Columbia Street Waterfront District"
        },
        {
          "id": 108,
          "name": "Red Hook"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Fort Greene",
        "id": 309,
        "weight": 3
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 59,
          "name": "Bedford Stuyvesant"
        },
        {
          "id": 71,
          "name": "Clinton Hill"
        },
        {
          "id": 86,
          "name": "Fort Greene"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Park Slope",
        "id": 310,
        "weight": 4
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 104,
          "name": "Park Slope"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Prospect Park - South",
        "id": 311,
        "weight": 5
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 78,
          "name": "Ditmas Park"
        },
        {
          "id": 94,
          "name": "Kensington"
        },
        {
          "id": 112,
          "name": "South Slope"
        },
        {
          "id": 116,
          "name": "Sunset Park"
        },
        {
          "id": 121,
          "name": "Windsor Terrace"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Prospect Park - East",
        "id": 308,
        "weight": 6
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 75,
          "name": "Crown Heights"
        },
        {
          "id": 81,
          "name": "East Flatbush"
        },
        {
          "id": 84,
          "name": "Flatbush"
        },
        {
          "id": 105,
          "name": "Prospect Heights"
        },
        {
          "id": 106,
          "name": "Prospect Lefferts Gardens"
        },
        {
          "id": 107,
          "name": "Prospect Park"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Williamsburg",
        "id": 312,
        "weight": 7
      },
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 67,
          "name": "Bushwick"
        },
        {
          "id": 83,
          "name": "East Williamsburg"
        },
        {
          "id": 92,
          "name": "Greenpoint"
        },
        {
          "id": 113,
          "name": "South Williamsburg"
        },
        {
          "id": 119,
          "name": "Williamsburg - North Side"
        },
        {
          "id": 120,
          "name": "Williamsburg - South Side"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "borough": {
    "name": "Queens",
    "id": 123,
    "weight": 3
  },
  "mappings": [
    {
      "macro": {
        "name": "Queens",
        "id": 124,
        "weight": 0
      },
```

Comment: So use sort() on the arrays and read the property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)